# How to make a Ludo piece go around the board?

Tags: java, arrays

So for our final project in school we got to pick our own thing to do. I decided to make the game Ludo, in Java. For starters I'm making a simplified version that goes around a square, not a plus-shape as it usually is. Im having trouble in drawing the piece going around the board. For starters Im just making the board be outlined, black circles, with a full circle moving around the board when you roll the dice. Check picture:
[The simplified Ludo Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra7aL.png)

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSide; i++) {
            g.drawOval(i*squareSize,0,squareSize,squareSize);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSide; i++) {
            g.drawOval(0,i*squareSize,squareSize,squareSize);
        }
        for (int i = boardSide; i > 0; i--) {
            g.drawOval(i*squareSize,boardSide-squareSize,squareSize,squareSize);
        }
        for (int i = boardSide; i > 0; i--) {
            g.drawOval(boardSide-squareSize,i*squareSize,squareSize,squareSize);
        }
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        switch (squares[squarePlace]%8){
            case 1 -> g.fillOval(0,0,squareSize,squareSize);
        }
    }
```

boardSide is the amount of squares on one side, squareSize is how big each square is and squares[] is an int array of all the squares on the board, all empty squares have a value of -1. squarePlace is an int keeping track off where the green square is and has the value 1.

Im thinking that I should use a switch-case to check where the green square is in the array. Then use %-operator to check if it should be on the top, right, bottom or left of the board. I just can't think off how I should do that. I need to check how far into the array the square is, or check the position in the array, and then use % but I dont know how.

Comment: What is the purpose of keeping track of the sides?  Is this important to the game?  If I start in the top left corner of a square, and continue following it's sides all the way back to my start point, I have basically walked a straight line.  Think now of an array, let's call it `squares[10]`.  If I start at the first index, `squares[0]` and walk all the way to the end, `squares[9]`, what happens if I walk one space forward?  In this case, I'll end up back at `squares[0]`.